# How to use a custom icon with a system tray baloon notification/tooltip using SWT?

Tags: java, swt, jface

I was wondering whether SWT/jface allow for specifying a custom icon (other than predefined SWT.ICON_ERROR | SWT.ICON_INFORMATION | SWT.ICON_WARNING) for the application system tray item balloon tooltip? I would like to do something like:

```
ToolTip tip = new ToolTip(shell, SWT.BALLOON);
tip.setText("Notification from a tray item");
tip.setMessage("Here is a message for the user.");
tip.setIcon("/path/to/custom/icon");
trayItem.setToolTip(tip);
```

I am aware that ToolTip clas does not have the setIcon() method. Is there any other way to achieve this? This would be very useful for application level notifications, etc. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This article might help you [SWT: Tray Icons and Tooltips](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t66093.html).

**EDIT**

It's not possible, those images are obtained from OS, and cannot be replaced. The `setImage()` method which are you calling is one of the `Tooltip` parent's method and the image is completely ignored by Tooltip class.

See [source codes for Tooltip SWT class](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/ToolTip.java.htm) and check the `public void setVisible (boolean visible)` method (almost at the end), there you can see where are those image icons obtained.

It might be nice [feature request](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/) for SWT team.

**EDIT2**

Article about [Custom Tooltip in Eclipse 3.1 RCP applications](http://jroller.com/ortegon/entry/custom_tooltip_using_eclipse_3) might answer your question. He uses Custom SWT controls from [Novocode toolkit](http://www.novocode.com/swt/), check the BalloonWindow (A Shell wrapper which creates balloon popup windows).

Comment: Sorry for the poorly worded question. I would like to add a custom icon to the tray item balloon tooltip, not the tray item itself. I corrected the question text accordingly.

Comment: Is there a way to achieve the same effect using jface ToolTips?